Is it possible to read out the mainboard serial number and the security identifier of a client with a Blazor Webassembly app
We are linking license files to specific target systems that are identified with the serial number of the mainboard and the security identifier (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secgloss/s-gly).
Today, users have to install a small tool on the target system where the software is going to be installed to read out the serial number and SID.
Is it possible to read out both information elements for the client from a Blazor WebAssembly app that is loaded from a server? The user would have to open the app in a browser on the target system where he or she wants to install the software later. The app should read out the data of this client(=target system).
I investigated this issue but all I get is the SID and serial number of the server where the Blazor app is hosted.

In my opinion, this is impossible to get the client computer SID or else. For security concern, modern browser is design to protect the user data and prevent the web browser to access the client system data, so it's impossible to achieve directly read the data inside the webassembly, since webassembly is also running at the browser not the computer.
One possible way is creating the client-side application or running some scripts to read these data and send it to the backend server.

Thank you for your input, Brando! A C# client app is what we have today. However, the process is not very convenient for the customer, because he also has to install some prerequisites before the client application can be used. A true zero-footprint solution would be much more convenient.

without breaking the browser sandbox and wasm's own sandbox this is impossible.  (that said WASM has been used to write exploits...  stack overflows and such... obviously that's not a proper solution though)
